# Angular CLI images not loading in css

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Getting ["404 Not Found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uAMg.png) Error when trying to reference an image(lead-bg.jpg) from "assets/images" [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BdfJ.png) directory in my Angular CLI Project.Whereas i am able to open the image in VS Code. 
This is on my local machine.
Also the same kind of issue happened to me with the .woff and .ttf fonts as well.

As i see server is trying to look for the image at localhost folder instead of the "assets/images" directory where there is no such folder for images.

Please help me out with this issue as i have put on hold many angular projects due to this issue..

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring the wrong path. try this

```
 background-image: url(./assets/images/lead-bg.jpg);
```

**.** => current path

**./assets** => navigate to assets folder from the current path

**./assets/images/lead-bg.jpg** => then to original image path

**..** => points to the parent folder from current directory which is above assets but not assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the quotes.

Try `background-image: url("../images/lead-bg.jpg");`